# iPhone "forward delete" workaround

Tags: iphone, keyboard

This question should not be categorized as a duplicate, since it is qualitatively different and much more detailed than the one that it supposedly duplicates. It has been viewed over 1000 times demonstrating the interest in such details, specifically how the keyboard could be used to provide the forward delete functionality using established methods that iPhone users have become accustomed to. Post like this give users away to provide ideas and release their frustration over those insisting that it cannot or should not be done.

1. I know there is no "forward delete" on iPhone keyboards
2. I also know the various ways of moving the cursor around so that you can use the delete key instead.

But this procedure is maddeningly time-consuming for someone who wants to forward delete all the time.

My question is: Is there a workaround for this problem? For example, there are several places where long-pressing does nothing, any one of which could become a useful forward delete key.

Here's a short list (illustrated in the image below): the shift key, the 123 key, the autotype area above the keyboard, the space below the spacebar, letters like "p" which have no long-press action.

[image]

Is there no way to program this, come up with an app, or a customized keyboard? It's hard for me to believe that with all the brilliant minds out there no one can come up with a better way. By the way I've wanted to have a forward delete key about five times while writing this post!

Please don't respond if you have a negative answer (which can never be proved). Let's wait for someone brilliant out there to share with us.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is an option with the built-in keyboard. The only way you could forward delete is to connect an external keyboard and hold down the <kbd>fn</kbd> key and press <kbd>delete</kbd> key.

Also, this same question was asked [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5112/how-can-i-forward-delete-on-ios) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16531/where-is-the-forward-delete-button-in-iphone-s-keyboard) on this site.